# How to create Proportional Stacked Column Chart in an easy way in Google Chart? And how to combine two charts?

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

Please help me im very new in google chart script. Can you give me the right script for stacked proportional column chart with no complicated code in Google chart? And how to combine two charts... Im so glad if you can help me. Thank you

Here's the sample photo of combine charts:

[image]

And here's the script for stacked proportional column chart with complicated code:

```
 function drawVisualization() {

 var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Year', 'Austria', 'Belgium', 'Czech Republic', 'Finland', 'France', 'Germany'],
    ['2003',  1336060,   3817614,       974066,       1104797,   6651824,  15727003],
    ['2004',  1538156,   3968305,       928875,       1151983,   5940129,  17356071],
    ['2005',  1576579,   4063225,       1063414,      1156441,   5714009,  16716049],
    ['2006',  1600652,   4604684,       940478,       1167979,   6190532,  18542843],
    ['2007',  1968113,   4013653,       1037079,      1207029,   6420270,  19564053],
    ['2008',  1901067,   6792087,       1037327,      1284795,   6240921,  19830493]
  ]);

  var view  = new google.visualization.DataView(data);

  var columns = [0];
  for (var i = 1; i < data.getNumberOfColumns(); i++) {
    // add a column that calculates the proportional value of this column to the total
    columns.push({
        type: 'number',
        label: data.getColumnLabel(i),
        calc: (function (col) {
            return function (dt, row) {
                var val = dt.getValue(row, col);
                var total = 0;
                for (var j = 1; j < dt.getNumberOfColumns(); j++) {
                    total += dt.getValue(row, j);
                }
                return (total == 0) ? null : {v: val / total, f: val.toString()}; 
            };
        })(i)
    });
    // add an annotation column that puts a label on the bar
    columns.push({
        type: 'string',
        role: 'annotation',
        sourceColumn: i,
        calc: 'stringify'
    });
}

view.setColumns(columns);

var options = {
    title:"Yearly Coffee Consumption by Country",
    width:1000, height:400,
    isStacked: true,
    hAxis: {title: "Year"},
    vAxis: {
        format: '#%'
    }
};
var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('visualization'));
chart.draw(view, options);

 }
google.load('visualization', '1', {packages:['corechart'], callback: drawVisualization});
```

Comment: That code works, and it happens to be the most direct means of creating a proportional stacked ColumnChart.  There is no less complicated way of doing it.

Comment: I see. Please can you explain how it works.. inside the "var columns"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`columns` is an array of column definitions that gets used by a DataView to set the data used by a chart.  In this case, the code creates a bunch of calculated columns that calculate the percent of the total sum in each row that a particular column represents.  This code:

```
columns.push({
    type: 'number',
    label: data.getColumnLabel(i),
    calc: (function (col) {
        return function (dt, row) {
            var val = dt.getValue(row, col);
            var total = 0;
            for (var j = 1; j < dt.getNumberOfColumns(); j++) {
                total += dt.getValue(row, j);
            }
            return (total == 0) ? null : {v: val / total, f: val.toString()}; 
        };
    })(i)
});
```

adds a column to the definition that uses the `calc` method to calculate the percentage.  The return value from this function is an object whose `v` property represents the value to chart (the percentage) and whose `f` property represents the string value to display in tooltips.

This code:

```
columns.push({
    type: 'string',
    role: 'annotation',
    sourceColumn: i,
    calc: 'stringify'
});
```

adds an annotation column to the columns array, which adds a label to each column.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. i have a question, how can i convert it to xslt? pls help me. i tried many time to convert it but im always failed, seems im very beginner in xslt

Comment: I've never used xslt before, so I can't help you with that.

Comment: I have another question.. How do I set a percentage axis, I mean like 0, 10%, 20%... because when I set a percentage axis, I get a large percentage like 0, 70%, 140%... but the highest percentage that I have in my data is 2.75%. how can I fix that? so the data and the v axis will be matched? thank you

Comment: Are your percentages entered as decimal values or as percents (ie, is `'2.75%'` entered as `2.75` or `0.0275`)?  The Visualization API expects percents to be in decimal format (the `0.0275`).  If your data is in percent notation, you need to quote the `%` symbol in the formatter, so it is treated as a string to append instead of the percent formatter: `"#'%'"`

Comment: Hi @asgallant !I have a question why the V-Axis of the proportional stacked column chart is like '0.5' and so on? How can i fixed that? I want a whole number like '0,10,20..' I try to put this format --> '#' but its not effective.

Comment: This function sets the value of a bar to its proportion of the total, which is what is plotted on the axis.  You can multiply the proportion by 100 if you want whole values on the axis instead of decimals: `return (total == 0) ? null : {v: 100 * val / total, f: val.toString()};`.  You can use a percent format for the vAxis as well: '#%'.

Comment: got it. i have another questions, when i run the script and see the display, why there's some 0 displayed at bottom of each column? even so my data are not zero? the 0 looks like a candle graph like a 0 with a tale

Comment: Using your example, I can't replicate that problem: http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/h8BHD/.  Can you create an example that demonstrates it?